# Create autocomplete based on a defined field in the forms.py file. Django -Python

Tags: django, forms, autocomplete

It tries to create the simplest autocomplete field based on a defined field (ChoiceField) in the forms.py file.  I was looking at the information forum, but most of all the answers refer to the autocomplete from the models.py file. 
An example of a field that is trying to create [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default).

How can I do it in the easiest way? Any help will be appreciated.

**forms.py**

```
class BasicForm(forms.Form):
    trade = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_WORK_CHOICES)
```

**app_choices.py**

```
TYPE_WORK_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'trade_1'),
    (2, 'trade_2'),
    (3, 'trade_3'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    form = BasicForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        trade = cd['trade']
        query_string = urlencode({'trade': trade})
        next_url = '{}?{}'.format(reverse('app:search'), query_string)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need autocomplete, when you have a choice field anyway? Are you rendering the choice field as a text input rather than dropdown? (I think a dropdown would be better as number of options seem to be very less). If you are rendering it as text field, you only need to specify the options in the source parameter. (Please elaborate the question a bit more)

Comment: My selection list will be very long, maybe even more than 20 options, I would like the user to be able to search for a matching field by entering part of the phrase. and finally get the effect like here 'http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox' The user has a lot of checkboxes, but by entering the first elements of the phrase, the number of possibilities is limited

Comment: The jquery combobox, needs the field to be just like the field that django renders. You can directly wrap the field in div with appropriate classes. (Django choice field also renders as a select) 

If the combobox needs choices to be in a list passed as json, you can make an ajax call to get the choices as json